# autohotkey cant read variables A_hour

Tags: if-statement, variables, autohotkey

This is my first script,
i want this script take variable from gui, then it will send CTRL+E to specific windows app based on certain time on variable time 1 and time 2

code only working until mytimer : (line 45), after that if statement is not working, no show msgbox, what is the problem?

thanks for help.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#SingleInstance,Force
;Gui Layout
;----------------------
hour:="00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|"
minute:="00||01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|"
SetTitleMatchMode,  2
SetTitleMatchMode, Fast
;Gui,Add,Text, x10, Timer control for toggle MT4 Auto Trading

Gui,Add,Text, x10, Insert your MT4 account ID :
Gui,Add,Edit, x+10 w100 vmtid
Gui,Add,Text, x10, Choose what time to toggle Auto Trading [on/off]
Gui,Add,Text, x10, Time 1 :
Gui,Add,Text, x10, Hour
Gui,Add,Text, x+50, Minutes 
Gui,Add,DropDownList, x10 w50 r10 vh1,% "16||"hour
Gui,Add,DropDownList, x+10 w50 r10 vm1,% minute

Gui,Add,Text, x10 y+10, Time 2 :
Gui,Add,Text, x10, Hour
Gui,Add,Text, x+50, Minutes 
Gui,Add,DropDownList, x10 w50 r10 vh2,% "22||"hour
Gui,Add,DropDownList, x+10 w50 r10 vm2,% minute

Gui,Add,Button, x10 y+20 w100 h50 gactive, Activate !

Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Show, x800 y100 w300 h300, MT4 Auto Trading Timer
return

active:
Gui,Submit, NoHide
    ;MsgBox, Starting, Running Script...
#Persistent
SetTimer, mytimer, 60000
return

mytimer:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
;MsgBox, %h1%:%m1% %mtid%  ;<---only until this is working
if (A_Hour = %h1% && A_Min = %m1%)  ;<from this its not working
{

    MsgBox, wow, it h1 show
    WinActivate, %mtid%
    WinWaitActive, %mtid% 
    Send, ^e
}
if (A_Hour = %h2% && A_Min = %m2%)
{

    ;MsgBox, wow2, it h2
    WinActivate, %mtid% 
    WinWaitActive, %mtid% 
    Send, ^e
}
return


^x::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake of using [legacy syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#legacy-syntax) where the modern, better, [expression syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#expressions-vs-legacy-syntax) should be used.

Inside an expression, which is what you're doing when you're inside `( )`, you don't use the legacy of referring to variables (wrapping them in `%%`). Instead you just type the name of the variable.
So your if statements should look like this:
`if (A_Hour = h1 && A_Min = m1)`

What you were doing before, and what the other answer here does, (wrapping the variables in `%%` in an expression statement), is pretty much referencing a pointer to a variable.
But when the pointer doesn't exist, the end result is just `nothing`.
`(%A_Hour% = %h1% && %A_Min% = %m1%)`
evaluates to
`("" = "" && "" = "")`
which is always true (assuming the pointers don't exist)
probably a bad explanation, it's hard to explain, but the point being, never wrap your variables inside `%%` in an expression.

Overall, I'd recommend getting rid of using legacy syntax. It's not 2008 anymore.
The documentation page, which I linked twice above, is a good reference to get started on understanding the differences.